# Java installer not working

Tags: windows-8, java

I just uninstalled java and downloaded the java installer again from the website . The version of the installer is jre-8u291 .
When I run it, nothing happened . It runs on background but not doing anything . No memory change, no cpu usage, etc . No interface at all , it just runs in background doing nothing.

[image: java]

How do I solve this ? I want to install java again asap pls help

EDIT : I found the source of the problem , so i uninstalled java then I want to reinstall but i got this problem . Then i try to run java program , in this case I run minecraft , IT WORKED ! that means java is not fully uninstalled . But i already uninstalled java in program and features and I have rechecked that there is no java in program and features !!!! how the heck did this happen , now I'm trying to find a way to uninstall java because it doesn't appear on program and features

EDIT : sorry I forgot to mention I am using windows 8

Comment: Are you sure you want the 32bit version of Java? On modern PCs with 64bit CPU you should install the 64bit ("x64") version.

Comment: i downloaded the 64 bit version , it doesnt work either

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Java completely, restart, and then download Java 291 64-bit from java.com and install the 64-bit version. Use the section "for another operating system.." so you can get the full installer and not just the stub installer.

Most systems are now 64-bit and Java 64-bit should work fine. I have it running on several systems here.

But java should be uninstalled first to eliminate 32-bit versions and then restart.

Make sure this is for personal use and if you are in a company that you are licensed to use Java.

Follow up: We learned that the machine is a Windows 8 machine and so fewer repair tools are available.

System File Checker was run and did not work and the author does not have the Windows 8 media to make a repair.

Accordingly, the practical way forward is to back up all data and reinstall Windows 8 from the recovery partition, or, better, upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: i did everything , i uninstalled the program from "Program and Features" and downloaded the x64 and the x32 , none of these worked , i also downloaded the offline uninstaller , doesnt work either .

Comment: Try running SFC.  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. Run SFC /SCANNOW . Allow it to finish, restart and test.

Comment: ok first of all , thanks so much for spending time to help me (i forgot to say it earlier) :) ! ok im running the command now , i will tell the result later

Comment: SFC can take 15 minutes to run. See what happens.

Comment: You may have an issue with the operating system causing this and the Java issue. I amended my answer to include repair steps.

Comment: Yep i have corrupt file and windows cannot fix it , i'm currently trying to fix it , and if i managed to fix it , i will try to install java again then come back here if it works or not , thanks so much !

Comment: If you cannot fix the damaged file, the Repair Install mentioned in my answer should fix it.

Comment: i edited the post and posted what i found

Comment: I read your edit and suggest you try the Repair I suggested. Something is wrong  "uninstall java because it doesnt appear on program and features"  You might consider first uninstalling Minecraft before the repair and install it after.

Comment: i did sfc and sfc could not fix it . And the windows repair you suggested is windows 10 but i am using windows 8

Comment: Do you have the Windows 8 installer? You might try repairing from that.

Comment: no :( i bought this laptop with windows already installed , i dont have the installer

Comment: I am not really sure what you can do at this point:  Reinstall Windows 8 or upgrade it to Windows 10.